# go - golang test parameterized

Tags: go, testing

In python I can easily do

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input, expected', [(1, 2), [2, 3]])
def test_tutu(input, expected):
    assert input + 1 == expected
```

How can I do the same in golang ? without writting myself a loop

```golang
func tutu(a int) int {
    return a + 1
}

func Test_tutu(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        input    int
        expected int
    }{
        {input: 1, expected: 2},
        {input: 2, expected: 3},
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
            assert.Equal(t, tutu(tt.input), tt.expected)
        })
    }
}
```

So what would be the equivalent of this python parametrize in golang ?

```py
def parametrize(all_args_name: str, all_values: List[Any], fn: Callable):
    args_name = all_args_name.split(',')
    for values in all_values:
        args = {k: v for k, v in zip(args_name, values)}
        fn(**args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using reflect

```golang
func parametrize[V any, T any](fn T, allValues [][]V) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    for _, a := range allValues {
        vargs := make([]reflect.Value, len(a))

        for i, b := range a {
            vargs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(b)
        }
        v.Call(vargs)
    }
}

func tutu(a int) int {
    return a + 1
}

func Test_tutu(t *testing.T) {
    testsArgs := [][]any{
        {t, 1, 2}, {t, 3, 4},
    }
    test := func(t *testing.T, input int, expected int) {
        assert.Equal(t, tutu(input), expected)
    }
    parametrize(test, testsArgs)
}
```

Comment: What do you like about your parameterize/reflection approach? I'm not new to Go, but I find that very difficult to read and understand. The explicit for-loop in your question is very readable.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing GO has is [subtests](https://go.dev/blog/subtests), but you would still need to write the `for` loop, like you already did in the second example.